# The specified 'redirect_uri' is not valid for this client application in OpenIdDict in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, openiddict

I have created two project and setup server in one project and in another setup a client. I have created database table to store the client information. I have also stored the RedirectUris in the database but every time I am getting the above error.

Can any one please suggest me what I am missing?

Server code:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()

        // Register the OpenIddict core components.
        .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                    // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<AuthDbContext>();

                    // Enable Quartz.NET integration.
                    options.UseQuartz();
                })

        // Register the OpenIddict server components.
        .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
                    options
                    .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                        .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                        .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                        .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

                    options
                       .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
                       .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                       .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                    options
                        .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                        .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
                        .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

                    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                    // Add all auth flows that you want to support

                    // Register your scopes
                    // Scopes are a list of identifiers used to specify what access privileges are requested.
                    options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

                    // Set the lifetime of your tokens
                    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
                    options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

                   // Register ASP.NET Core host and configure options
                   options.UseAspNetCore()
                          .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                          .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                          .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                          .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                          .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
                })

        // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
        .AddValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
                    options.UseLocalServer();

                    // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                    options.UseAspNetCore();
                });
```

Client code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                // Note: these settings must match the application details
                // inserted in the database at the server level.
                options.ClientId = {ClientId};
                options.ClientSecret = {ClientSecret };
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                // Use the authorization code flow.
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44312";

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Uri, ClaimTypes.Uri, "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, ClaimTypes.GivenName, "string");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, ClaimTypes.Surname, "string");

                options.SecurityTokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
                {
                    // Disable the built-in JWT claims mapping feature.
                    InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

I have checked so many documents from the internet but didn't found any proper solutions

Comment: Did you create the background worker to register the client ids and client secrets?

Answer (score 0):

Create a client and set the redirectURI

```cs
    public class TestData : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public TestData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FaDbContext>();
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync(cancellationToken);

            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();
            var client = await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("postman", cancellationToken);
            if (client is null)
            {
                await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "postman",
                    ClientSecret = "postman-secret",
                    DisplayName = "Postman Client",
                    RedirectUris = { new Uri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback") },
                    Permissions =
                    {
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                        //OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.Password,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Roles,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Address,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Phone,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "faid_client_scope",
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "test_scope_1",

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.IdToken,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Token
                    },

                }, cancellationToken);
            }


        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Then register in program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
```

there is a guide on how to do it here:
https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-iii-client-credentials-flow-55lp